# AttributeError while using Replace function

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Sorry if this is already answered somewhere but I tried almost every answered post for this query but due to less experience in python I am not able to solve this.

```
line 38, in on_message
    msg1 = msg.replace("EmbedProxy", "")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

This is snippet of main code

```
msg = message.embeds[0].fields
        remove_characters = ["Machine Name:", "Threads", "Log", "Runtime", "Total Errors", "Content Mapped", " ContentMapped/h/thread", "Total Content", "Total Result", ":", ""]
        for character in remove_characters:
            msg = msg.replace(character, "")
            result1 = [x.strip() for x in msg.split('|')]
        #if len(result) == FIELDS:
            # Add
        print(message.created_at)
        DATA = [str(message.created_at)] + result1
        sheet.add(SPREADSHEET_ID, RANGE_NAME, DATA)
        await message.channel.send('Your data has been successfully submitted!')
```

Output of msg = message.embeds[0].fields is

> [EmbedProxy(value='16Core-64GB', name=':computer: Machine Name:',
> inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='120', name=':zap: Threads:',
> inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='72s', name=':hourglass_flowing_sand:
> Runtime:', inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='0.25h', name=':timer: Total
> Errors:', inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='1002', name=':loud_sound:
> ContentMapped/h/thread:', inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='4008',
> name=':watch: Total Content:', inline=True), EmbedProxy(value='33',
> name=':battery: Total Result:', inline=True)]

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace something in the lists. At first, you have to turn them into string with
`msg = ' '.join(msg)`. Then you can replace whatever you want in `msg` variable.

Comment: I tried this as well in past and just did that and getting this error.

msg = ' '.join(msg)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, EmbedProxy found

Comment: So, can you try `msg = ' '.join(list(msg))`?

Comment: Still same.

in on_message
    msg = ' '.join(list(msg))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, EmbedProxy found

Comment: Can you try to do `for i in msg: print i`

Comment: got this error msg = msg.replace(character, "")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'